# MongoCursorTimeoutException with php zend framework2 solve by Python integration

Tags: php, python, mongodb, zend-framework2

i am working on a big project technology used (php zend framework2 + mongodb) that can have more than million records and after some time it may be billion records.
My Question have two parts

1. So i am facing with MongoCursorTimeoutExceptions issue. i have any idea that if i integrate Python ( that is famous to handle big data ) is it a good idea?
2. If yes then please give me a better way to integrate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same monogodb timeout exceptions issue have met even python also,

One way:

1. you can create indexes on mongodb and handle those data, (you should use mongodb hint option on your coding)

Another Way:

1. Store the filter values and primary key into solr
2. Call the solr with filter queries and get the primary keys
3. Based on primary keys can retrieve those data from mongodb

Hope those points will help to you